# I want to create custom flight search form in wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, forms, api, search

I'm working on an aviation company website and i finished the wordpress site and upload it to their hosting, but they asked me to create a custom search form and connect it with their booking system using a url they gave me with the documentation of the integration but this the first time for me to work with API URLs and this integration concepts.

They gave me two days to solve this so please help me.

Thanks

Comment: This is a too broad question. Try to split it in smaller MREs https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and don't forget to add you current code or what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all not accept such an unreasable request. Second, you can better contract a programmer to do such a thing. Its an overstretch to do that without experience. But then still two days is probably too little.

Comment: I asked them for more days to solve this problem. I just want to know the steps to do this or if there is an article which contain what i want.

Comment: I fear this is not a one article how-to-do-it problem, but it requires quite some understanding. If you are not experienced, i recommend you search somebody to do it for you and let them invoice you so you can invoice the customer.